# How to render two components in the same path according to Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an application that have three simple views like following:

```
Homepage - Simple page with information texts
Register - Asks for e-mail and passwords and register users
Logged - When registration done, this page displays buyable items
```

After registration done a back-end server returns token and I store it to window.localStorage. I want to show "Homepage" when there is no token in the browser, if so "Logged" page should be displayed. I also want them to have same path: "/"

How to achieve this?

**router.js**

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            get component() {
                // This code works but when this.$router.push("/") executed from Register, Home is rendered unless page is refreshed
                if(typeof Store.getters.token === "undefined") return Home;
                return Logged;
            },
        },
        {
            path: "/register",
            component: Register
        }
    ]
});
```

**register.vue**

```
            this.$http.post("register", {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.$store.commit("setToken", response.data.token);
                this.$router.push("/"); // Homepage is rendered unless page is refreshed
            })
```

Comment: You can have a simple piece of data for example `isAuthenticated` and set it to false by default and when your server respond with the token or you already have it in your localstorage you can set to true, after then you can have [v-if v-else directives](https://alligator.io/vuejs/conditional-directives/)

Comment: @AmrAly It is logical. However, in App.vue I only have <router-view />. Is there any other solution for this? Or will I have to add views and add v-if 
v-else conditions to App.vue?

Comment: you can add `v-if v-else` directives in the component associated with '/' path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this situation by;

1. Defining two *components* named **Homepage** and **Logged** and importing them inside a one *view* named **Index**
2. Inside Index View, put Logged and Homepage component to template and make a **v-if** to decide to use Logged or Homepage component like;

**Index.vue**

```js
<template>
  <Homepage v-if="typeof $store.getters.token === 'undefined'"/>
  <Logged v-else />
</template>
<script>
   import Logged from '../components/Logged'
   import Homepage from '../components/Homepage'
      export default {
        components: {
         Logged,
         Homepage
      },
    }
</script>
```

**router.js**

```js
const Index = () => import('./views/Index.vue');
const Register = () => import('./views/Register.vue');

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: Index
        },
        {
            path: "/register",
            component: Register
        }
    ]
});
```